# get parent's siblings number went its child was click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML and when tag was click I want to know that what is its `<li>` siblings number was. Please Advice me please.

```
 <div id="tabs">
       <ul>
           <li class="select" ><a href="#" id="tabHotel">Hotel</a></li>
           <li ><a href="#" id="tabAirfare">Airfare</a></li>
           <li ><a href="#" id="tabPackage">Package</a></li>
       </ul>
  </div>
```

and here is my javascript.

```
// I don't want to input 1 in the function tabSelector 
// I want to get parent's sibling value automatic and 
// change somthing in li class.

$('#tabHotel').click(function(){
    tabSelector(1);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

```
$("#tabs").on("click", "li", function(){
   alert($(this).index());
});
```

in your case:

```
tabSelector($(this).index() + 1 );
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/P3KjZ/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [**index()**](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method to achieve this I believe.

> index() - If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.
>
> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or
>   jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the
>   position of the passed element relative to the original collection

[**Here's a jsFiddle example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/6b9zy/2/)

---

For the technical number (first is equal to 0) you'd use:

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
   console.log($(this).index());
});
```

For the literal number (first element is equal to one) you'd just add one to the index instead:

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
   console.log($(this).index()+1);
});
```

Comment: as $(this).index() gives value from 0 we will be requried to add 1 to return value to get exact value

Answer (score 0):

to get exact number you will be required to add 1 to the index. please try below one

```
$("#tabs").on("click", "li", function(){
       alert($(this).index()+1)
    })
```